# How to use DI with construct parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have custom class that I inject to another component class:

```
export class FormRegister implements IFormRegister, IFormControl {
}

export class A {
 constructor(public formRegister: FormRegister) {
 }
}
```

It works fine, bu if I add constructor to class `FormRegister()` like:

```
export class FormRegister implements IFormRegister, IFormControl {
   construct(private newDependence: Dep)
}
```

It generates error in class A:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormRegister: (?).
```

Because it does not have `private newDependence: Dep` as parameter.

How to use DI with construct parameter?

I tried this:

```
export class A {
     constructor(public formRegister: new FormRegister(this.newDependence)) {
     }
    }
```

Comment: what library are you using for dependency injection?

Comment: It is my own class

Comment: are you writing an angular application?

Comment: dependency injection is usually handled by some technology/library that makes sure all dependencies are met. What you seem to be doing is just trying to instantiate a class. You have to provide the dependencies yourself when you create it.

Comment: I think I need pass dependency for `FormRegister,` directly in ngModule in import section

Comment: also `constructor(public formRegister: new FormRegister(this.newDependence))` is wrong, maybe you meant `constructor(public formRegister = new FormRegister(this.newDependence))` ? To make the form register default parameter value a new instance of the FormRegister class?

Comment: is this an angular app? then you are missing the @Injectable annotations :-/ please post a complete example of your problem.

Comment: When I register `FormRegister` I need to pass dependency injections for that

Comment: classes only get picked up by the angular dependency injection if they are decorated with @Injectable or one of the other decorators. Please make a complete minimal verifiable example of the problem. Maybe on stackblitz

Comment: I have custom class `FormRegister`. I registered this class in ngModule. Then I use this in component as DI, in constructor. But I get an error, cause injected class has constructor with another DI. It is simple, I showed all code in question

Comment: May be to use like this: `{provide: FormRegister, useClass: Title },` in ngModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution, let assume we have custom class to inject in any component:

```
export class FormRegister implements IFormRegister, IFormControl {

  public constructor(public titleService: Title) {

  }

}
```

Before we must to register this class/service in `NgModule` in provider section:

```
providers: [
  FormRegister
]
```

You can notice our class/service uses DI in constructor. To avoid error just add this decorator before class `FormRegister`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
  useFactory: () => new FormRegister(Title),
})

export class FormRegister implements IFormRegister, IFormControl {
}
```

Where `useFactory: () => new FormRegister(Title),` means we use DI of `Title`

Comment: It does not work in old version Angular, it complaints on line `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
  useFactory: () => new FormRegister(Title),
})`: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`